# What is this Perspex bubble?

Tags: military

Found this during a garden clearance. Have included a photo of serial number. Could you identify where this came from?

[image]
[image: serial number]

dimensions: width 115cm length 140cm.

[image: side view]

[image: close up]

Comment: Do you have any further details? Which country, area (perhaps nearby air bases etc.)?

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE could you clarify what you want us to identify? I am thinking of type of aircraft but I do not know what you are looking for.

Comment: Has two circular holes approx 10cm diameter at end opposite hinges. Label states MODS and serial number. Its in Essex now, but think it was transported here. Keen to find out what aircraft and what it is.

Comment: Could you please re-do the first photo trying to avoid all that blurring/noise? use a camera, not a phone, and try to have better lighting conditions. thank you

Comment: Could you please add the dimensions?

Comment: Have some other photos but site wont let me add any more.

Comment: have serial number etc but blurred as perspex milky. Mentions MODS? The base is flat so could that even be for an aircraft?. Dimensions approx110cm x130cm.

Comment: @mike Would you like me to add the photos and information from your [most recent question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/25431/12720) to this question?

Comment: I've added the photos you posted in you other question, but 1. I do not see the resemblance 2. the new photos are reeeeeally tiny

Comment: Are the two new pictures of the same canopy? The shapes of the objects in the two middle pictures look very, very different. Where, on the 3rd picture, are the latches visible in the 2nd picture? Maybe try some pictures against an uncluttered background, like a tarp or a driveway - something that would help eliminate background distractions.

Answer (score 2):

Few thoughts:

- Label font does look British/Commonwealth in some way.
- Flat bottom- unlikely to be cockpit canopy that curve down on the sides.
- Not compatible with weapons- Search and Rescue aircraft?
- Large curvature: Slow aircraft?

---

At some point I was considering the rear window of the Consolidated Catalina but it doesn't quite seem to fit the bill.

[image]

<sub>Tony Hisgett on Wikicommons/[Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Consolidated_PBY_Catalina_2_%287509915628%29.jpg)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The hole you show in the other post tells me it is not a gun turret. The hole has a small diameter and looks like a series of screw holes around the edge. This could be a sensor or access panel fitment point. The dome itself could be a housing for a strike/ recon camera. It might have fitted to a self contained pod that fitted to an aircraft or be part of a recon aircraft fairing. There is not much to go on and with no access to service parts records you are going to be hard pushed to identify it for sure, hell... it could even be an old truck part.